# How can I fetch a URL link from the contents of an email body?

Tags: java, selenium

This is the body of the email:

```
********************
We welcome you to partner with our team of healthcare professionals who understand that overweight and obesity are chronic diseases that need to be managed with customized strategies that feel sustainable long-term. Our providers know that weight management requires more than willpower or strategies like “eat less, exercise more.”
Why choose us?
This program is based on over 20 years of data from more than 15,000 patients, and we’ve been paying attention to how every person has unique needs. We want to use our expertise to develop an individualized plan for you based on your experiences, preferences and health goals.
Together, we are confident that you can achieve success with small goals, personalized medical support, and regular check-ins using our unique digital tools.
Are you ready to try something new?

Get started today ( https://u9738139.ct.sendgrid.net/ls/click?upn=BPEdlQPL1bTBzMFJ4T-2FMSCLqyVGH4nH5Cfahbthey41XetxY34HDkr5T5zC4sod3uaKeK1sQ2hv3M8UWc0NU3G3qMthcFEim4vQi8vyR-2F9NYZ-2FGIPe0dzJm6-2F7HIyvWtbkCG_XkrR9c0nYokBbJ8TuCFj-2BC03XiEeoSVfuQJx5sQrjHj1ko1Y-2B1cKxdZ22agHjQ3rK6958qBRpuWhh5sSlijNCenODaXDwme2nvzNoeftMeOvmv-2BXVXTkliUzC7-2FJjbFZaUXX5Sw-2Fa2h2cR2ejDOejVAta2dptzwQFmYhjNE6r4BS60viWDenxQdHxNiNxU32f4ONs2UWbHkKOrAl3kZYeryRfKcO2hz6fRCnw1KFcDQGL0tlRkZb-2BGrOIzd1fCsW )
```

I need to retrieve only the URL (without brackets) which is present under "Get Started Today." Please guide me to retrieve the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to retrieve URL from your string content, if your content exactly like that you sent:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

....

String line = "...."; // Your web content
String pattern = "\\(\\s(.*)\\s\\)"; // Your URL is between () with 1 space on both sides

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

if (m.find( )) {
   System.out.println("URL: " + m.group(1) );
}else {
   System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

Comment: Hi @navand, The above piece of code which you have given works fine for Windows environment, but it is not working in Linux. Pattern is not matching and test cases are failing when executing in Linux. Could you please guide me what need to be done for the code to work in Linux??.

Comment: Hi, I searched about different behavior of selenium on windows and linux, It seems that there are exist some difference, could you please check it? Or share the contents?

Comment: sure will check that. Thank you